# How to make this program?

Tags: c, if-statement, do-while, strcmp, strlen

I'm a newbie on this.
Can anyone help me to create this program?
I got no idea how to make this program.
Here's the description of the program.

> created a program with the following features.
>
> ■ Function
>
> enter the reference character string first.
>
> Then, check if they match the criteria string
>
> Counts the number of times if a match is found, and display
>
> Display an error if it does not find a match.
>
> And when we input string
>   "end" the program will be closed.
>
> ■ Notes · use the function **strlen** First, and use function **strcmp** next.
>
> ■ run example (reference)
>
> Please type the reference string: call
>
> Please type [end] when you are finished.
>
> call
>
> Matched. Once
>
> call
>
> Matched. Twice
>
> ccccccccccc
>
> Input error
>
> call
>
> Matched. Three times
>
> end
>
> To exit

I have tried to make one
and I made it like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main ()
{
    while(1000)
  {
  char call[]="call";
  char word[80];

     printf ("please type call: ");
     gets (word);

  if(strcmp(word,"call")==0)
  puts("matched!\n");
  else
  puts("error\n");
  }
  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: strcmp doesn't return `NULL` but an integer, so you if you want to check whether two strings are the same you should check if it returns 0 e.g. `if(strcmp("a", "a") == 0) { printf("The strings are the same\n"); }`

Comment: what doesn't work with your program? What is your question? SO is not a cite for code review.

Comment: you aren't doing what is requested at all. look at the requirements and the example, and then look at your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void){
    char criteria[] = "call";
    char *mes[] = { "Many times", "Once", "Twice", "Three times" };
    char word[80];
    int match_count =0, not_end=1;

    do{
        printf(
            "Please type the reference string.\n"
            "Please type [end] when you are finished.\n"
            ">");
        fgets(word, sizeof(word), stdin);
        int len = strlen(word);
        if(word[len-1]=='\n')
            word[--len]='\0';
        if(strcmp(word, criteria)==0){
            if(++match_count > 3)
                printf("Matched. %s(%d)\n", *mes, match_count);
            else
                printf("Matched. %s\n", mes[match_count]);
        } else if(not_end=strcmp(word, "end"))
            printf("Input error\n");
    }while(not_end);
    printf("Bye!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: int len = strlen(word);
        if(word[len-1]=='\n')
            word[--len]='\0';

@BLUEPIXY can you explain this code for me? thanks :)
英語がだめだったら日本語でもいい。よろしく～

Comment: @Rudy fgetsは(getsと違って)基本改行を含めて読み込む(指定した文字数－１に達した場合は別)ので、まず改行の有無を確認し改行が存在する場合はEOS('\0')文字列終端文字に置き換える。

Comment: あの、すいません。やっぱりword[len-1]とword[--len]ってどう言うことか分からないんです。

Comment: @Rudy 仮に(wordに)読み込んだ文字列が"abcd\n"だったとすると、この文字列の長さ(len)は５になりますね。配列のインデックスは０から始まるのでword[0]:'a',..,word[3]:'d'のようになり、その時最後の文字である改行は文字列の長さ－１のインデックスの文字になります（０からはじまるので－１）。それでword[len-1]はword[4]で、この時len が５で--len することはlen を４にすることですが、word[4]='\0'することは配列wordの内容を"abcd\0"にすることになります。word[--len]とせずにword[len-1]='\0'しても同じですが文字列の終端を一つ繰り上げたことで文字列の長さも１つ減るので--len すれば文字列の長さを表している変数lenの整合性が取れることになります。

Answer (score 0):

Your first error is using strcmp() wrong. strcmp() has nothing to do with NULL. It returns a negative number, a positive one, or zero.

Also, your test for "wrong, please try again" makes no sense.